# StringBuilder manipulation

Tags: java

How to get the actual string from variable `a` in the same method as insert method?

```
String a="test";
char[] g = a.toCharArray();
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = g.length; i > 0; i--) {
    str.insert(0,i);
}
```

Comment: This is very unclear what you're asking, please explain

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: Why do you wanna 'get the actual string from variable a in the same method' ? Are you clear about your question and your code ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
for (int i = g.length; i > 0; i--) {
    str.insert(0, i);
}
```

...With this:

```
for (int i = g.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    str.insert(0, a.charAt(i));
}
```

You insert numbers at the beginning of builder starting from integer 4 (`g.length`) to 1 in for loop. You should insert `a.charAt(i)` to get the expected result, `"test"`. Also, index `i` should point last character of string `a` at first and continue to insert till the character at index 0. To do this, it should start from `g.length - 1`, not `g.length`.

Comment: Btw, char array g seems redundant. You can do the same thing just using string a. Figure it out yourself.